# How I can get the watt from this datasheet? There is only current and voltage

Tags: voltage, current, datasheet, watts

[image: table]

I need the method that I can do to get the watt

It says 250mW but how? I need that because I need to get the minimum voltage and also to get the current in some cases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe not a full answer (as I don't have all the information needed), but at least a partial answer.

First of all "watt" is a measure of power. It don't says what kind of power.
From what I can guess from the extract of your datasheet (please provide a link to the full datasheet), I suspect it is an infrared LED.
If so, you have 2 different powers: electrical power (i.e. the power consumption of the LED) and optical power (i.e. the power of the IR light emitted). For an ideal LED it would be the same, in practice there is probably a huge difference (because of limited efficiency of LEDs, the rest of the electrical power being transformed into heat).

From the 1st line, we learn that at 700 mA, the voltage is typically 1.7 V, and maximum 2 V. So if you supply 700 mA to the LED, the power consumption will typically be $$P_{elec}=0.7 A*1.7 V=1.19 W$$ and at most $$0.7 A*2 V=1.4 W$$

From the 4th line, we learn that if the current is 700 mA (ie electrical power around 1.19 W), then the optical power P<sub>O</sub>=P_optical is typically 250 mW (i.e. 0.25 W), and at least 0.2 W.

By comparing the electrical power 1.19 W) and the optical power (0.25 W), you can see that the efficiency is about 20% (i.e. 1/5th of the power is transformed into IR light, the rest is wasted as heat).

Comment: Actually its very good answer (there is alot of info that i didn't know before reading your answer )  and yeah thank you very much and this is the pdf maybe there is an important info that i didnt put in my question https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/635258/OPTOSUPPLY/OSI3XNE3E1E.html

Comment: Its a rather "poor" datasheet, but it still has some useful additional data : in the absolute maximums, the max current is 1A, and the max power is 2A : so you can slightly increase the current above 700mA if needed, but not by much (and if you care about reliability, I would recommend to stay at or bellow 700mA). It also shows that the voltage don't varies much with current (around 700mA) because at 1A, we have 2W/1A=2V. So basically, the optical power will be roughly proportional to the current, and the voltage will only slightly decrease if you reduce current.

Comment: So you can't use a voltage source directly to power your LED : either you take a constant current source of 700mA or less, or you use a voltage source with voltage U (in V), and add a resistor (R, in ohms) in series with the LED depending on the current I (in A) you want : R = (V-1.7)/I should be a rather good choice. Make sure the power rating of the resistor is at least P=R*I² (with some margin)

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I have only one question left : does it will hurt my led if i give it above the typical voltage wich is 1.7 (to get more light) but not above the maximum wich is 2v /so its ok 1.7v or 1.8.? Or even 1.9 (all that just to give more brightness)

Comment: The voltage in itself doesn't matters. What matters is current 2A is the absolute maximum, exceeding it will damage/destroy the LED. The "problem" is that changing a little bit the voltage will hugely change the current (by how much is not specified in this datasheet). Fixing a voltage is NOT the correct way to control a LED : you have to fix the current. If you don't care much about efficiency, then just use a resistor as explained in my previous current (with I<<2A). If efficiency is important, then you need a dedicated LED drive (this is out of scope of this post, so best ask a new question

Comment: But I would definitively not advise you to put 2V on your LED without limiting the current. Also note that the 2A is an absolute limit (ie 2.01A for even a short instant might damage your LED). Also note that it doesn't account for overheating (max internal temperature is 85°C). So if you don't have a very good heatsink, don't even go near 2A. Start low (0.5A or bellow), and check temperature : if still cool after a few minutes, you can increase current

Comment: Ahm...actually im very new to this things and i think im asking alot.... Do you have telegram? If yes can i get your username i have some questions and thank you

Comment: If you have question, just ask them, it's what this site is made for. If your question goes beyond the original question, then just create a new one (it's far better than add new questions to an existing one). If you think this one gives useful context to the new one, just add a link to it (but put all essential information in the new question). And no, I don't have telegram, and I'm not intending to answer any questions "in private" : just create a new topic, and if the question is good, you will get several answers (for my part, I probably won't have time to write any before next week)

Answer (score 2):

> *I need the method that i can do to get the watt*

Current multiplied by voltage is power or, what you call "the watt". So, when the optical device is biased at around 1.7 volts with a forward current of 700 mA, the input power is 1.19 watts and, the optical output power is 250 mW, a power efficiency of 21% (about par for the course for optical devices like this).

Comment: Thank you for the info about the naming in first 2 line and for the clarifying

Answer (score 2):

You can get an estimate of the power with typical voltage/current characteristics. At a DC forward voltage we have 700mA x 1.7V which is 1.19W. Most of that power will be dissipate as heat, and you will have 250mW of optical power at that 700mA current level.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifying